# Cassandra: how to move whole tables to another keyspace

Tags: cassandra

Version info of my Cassandra:

> [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.5 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]

I am trying to move some huge tables (several million rows) to another keyspace. Besides "COPY to csv, and COPY from csv", is there any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get this to work on a single-node cluster running 2.2.8.

I experimented by moving my `holidays` table from my `presentation` keyspace over to my `stackoverflow` keyspace.

Here are the steps I took:

**Create the table inside the new keyspace.**

This step is important, because each table has a UUID for a unique identifier, stored in the `system.schema_columnfamilies` table in the `cf_id` column.  This id is attached to the directory names that hold the data.  By copy/pasting the schema from one keyspace to another, you'll ensure that the same column names are used, but that a new unique identifier is generated.

Note: In 3.x, the identifier is stored in the `system_schema.tables` table.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> CREATE TABLE holidays (
 type text,
 eventtime timestamp,
 beginend text,
 name text,
 PRIMARY KEY (type, eventtime, beginend)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (eventtime DESC, beginend DESC);

aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM stackoverflow.holidays ;

 type | eventtime | beginend | name
------+-----------+----------+------

(0 rows)
```

**Stop your node(s) properly (DISABLEGOSSIP, DRAIN, kill/stop, etc...).**

**Now, find the location of the old and new table on disk, and copy/move the files to the new location** (from the old location):

```
$ ls -al /var/lib/cassandra/data22/stackoverflow/holidays-77a767e0a5f111e6a2bebd9d201c4c8f/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 aploetz aploetz 4096 Nov  8 14:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 17 aploetz aploetz 4096 Nov  8 14:25 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 aploetz aploetz 4096 Nov  8 14:25 backups
$ cp /var/lib/cassandra/data22/presentation/holidays-74bcfde0139011e6a67c2575e6398503/la* /var/lib/cassandra/data22/stackoverflow/holidays-77a767e0a5f111e6a2bebd9d201c4c8f/

$ ls -al /var/lib/cassandra/data22/stackoverflow/holidays-77a767e0a5f111e6a2bebd9d201c4c8f/
drwxrwxr-x  3 aploetz aploetz 4096 Nov  8 14:26 .
drwxrwxr-x 17 aploetz aploetz 4096 Nov  8 14:25 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 aploetz aploetz 4096 Nov  8 14:25 backups
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   43 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz  628 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-Data.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz    9 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-Digest.adler32
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   16 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-Filter.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   57 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-Index.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz 4468 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-Statistics.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   94 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-Summary.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   94 Nov  8 14:26 la-1-big-TOC.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   43 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-CompressionInfo.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz  164 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-Data.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   10 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-Digest.adler32
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   16 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-Filter.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   26 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-Index.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz 4460 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-Statistics.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz  108 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-Summary.db
-rw-rw-r--  1 aploetz aploetz   94 Nov  8 14:26 la-2-big-TOC.txt
```

**Restart your node(s).**

**Query via cqlsh:**

```
Connected to SnakesAndArrows at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
aploetz@cqlsh> SELECT * FROM stackoverflow.holidays ;

 type         | eventtime                | beginend | name
--------------+--------------------------+----------+------------------------
    Religious | 2016-12-26 05:59:59+0000 |        E |              Christmas
    Religious | 2016-12-25 06:00:00+0000 |        B |              Christmas
    Religious | 2016-03-28 04:59:59+0000 |        E |                 Easter
    Religious | 2016-03-27 05:00:00+0000 |        B |                 Easter
 presentation | 2016-05-06 20:40:08+0000 |        B |        my presentation
 presentation | 2016-05-06 20:40:03+0000 |        B |        my presentation
 presentation | 2016-05-06 20:39:15+0000 |        B |        my presentation
 presentation | 2016-05-06 20:38:10+0000 |        B |        my presentation
           US | 2016-07-05 04:59:59+0000 |        E |            4th of July
           US | 2016-07-04 05:00:00+0000 |        B |            4th of July
           US | 2016-05-09 04:59:59+0000 |        E |            Mothers Day
           US | 2016-05-08 05:00:00+0000 |        B |            Mothers Day
         Nerd | 2016-12-22 05:59:59+0000 |        E |               2112 Day
         Nerd | 2016-12-21 06:00:00+0000 |        B |               2112 Day
         Nerd | 2016-09-26 04:59:59+0000 |        E |             Hobbit Day
         Nerd | 2016-09-25 05:00:00+0000 |        B |             Hobbit Day
         Nerd | 2016-09-20 04:59:59+0000 |        E | Talk Like a Pirate Day
         Nerd | 2016-09-19 05:00:00+0000 |        B | Talk Like a Pirate Day
         Nerd | 2016-05-07 04:59:59+0000 |        E |         Star Wars Week
         Nerd | 2016-05-04 05:00:00+0000 |        B |         Star Wars Week
         Nerd | 2016-03-14 05:00:00+0000 |        E |                 Pi Day
         Nerd | 2016-03-14 05:00:00+0000 |        B |                 Pi Day

(22 rows)
```

The problem with this approach, is that you will need to stop the cluster, and move files around on each node.  Whereas cqlsh `COPY` would allow you to import and export on a single node, with the cluster still running.

And I know that `COPY` has this reputation that limits it to smaller datasets.  But 2.2.x has options that help throttle COPY to keep it from timing out on large datasets.  I recently got it export/import 370 million rows without a timeout.