# Restore Cassandra snapshot to new keyspace in same cluster

Tags: cassandra

I've found documentation on restoring a keyspace snapshot to the same keyspace and also restoring it to a new cluster.  However, I'm trying to make a copy of a keyspace in Cassandra and cannot find how to restore a snapshot to a new keyspace.  Does anyone know if this is possible or have other recommendations on how to make a copy of the keyspace?

Comment: If you can afford to dump the data again or to restore the snapshot in a new cluster and then dump it, then you could use the [COPY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command. It works table by table though.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494304/cassandra-how-to-move-whole-tables-to-another-keyspace)?

Comment: For some reason we can't get COPY to work.  The data has a bunch of \n and they don't come through correctly.  The creating a new table option looks like it will work, will try.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
In your new keyspace, redefine the column families the same way as they were defined in the old keyspace. You can get the list of commands by running this cql:

DESCRIBE KEYSPACE ;

Note that here, your keyspace replication factor, etc shall remain the same.

Step 2 (do this on each node):
Under the old keyspace folder inside Cassandra data directory, there should be a snapshot folder per ColumnFamily. Copy the SSTables directly from the snapshot folders to the relevant ColumnFamily folders of the new keyspace inside Cassandra directory.

Step 3:
Do a rolling restart, and run repair on each node.